# json stringify remove text outside bracket

Tags: javascript

i'm using firebase function.
the code like this.

```
let transaction_id;
let signature_key;   
switch (req.get('Content-Type')) {
        case 'application/json':
    
          ({transaction_id} = req.body);
          ({signature_key} = req.body);
    
          break;
    
        case 'application/octet-stream':
          transaction_id = req.body.toString();
          signature_key = req.body.toString();
          break;
    
        case 'text/plain':
          transaction_id = req.body;
          signature_key = req.body;
          break;
    
        case 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
          ({transaction_id} = req.body);
          ({signature_key} = req.body);
          break;
      }
      console.log(transaction_id);
```

it still showing undefined.
console log req.body not showing json response.
[image]
the i try to JSON.Stringify.

```
Transaction status is pending {"transaction_id":"1c133665-d73d-45b6-b183-8d263644736b","signature_key":"TzbgFmtPe5qLu1MPcId3MoRcyU%2FBRWHJ6AdQQdLHN6ABy0SpB56F4jYUPFLMemPYL8KhruaQvWWYpAUEXJhcnpQ0Qn%2FHbE0GRwx1Em3Hc%2FWi1mofPUafALccvUmRR3QE","status":"OK","amount":"1020000.00","shipping_address":{},"payment_type":"30_days","transaction_status":"pending","transaction_time":1593094347,"order_id":"P-2020237834543138"}
```

when i do JSON.stringify it show up above data.
how to remove text outside curly bracket {} so i can convert to json to get value on transaction_id and signature_key?
or how to get the data directly from JSON.stringify output?

Comment: use `JSON.parse`

Comment: Can you show the code where `JSON.stringify` returns above output?

Comment: @demkovych, when i use JSON.parse, i get error SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: @palaѕн, (https://imgur.com/qC7cxk4)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the the transaction_id and signature_key from the JSON, you can do this

```js
var parsedData = JSON.parse(yourJsonString);

var transaction_id = parsedData.transaction_id
var signature_id = parseedData.signature_id;
```

Not sure, but is this what you want?

Comment: JSON.parse produce error SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1.
there is a string before json data

Comment: Thats means its already parsed, so try take away the JSON.parse() from the first line, so that parsedData just points to yourJsonString and try again

Comment: Okay, try looking at this code pen because it seems to be working for me. https://codepen.io/TEK-Projects/pen/GRoEYKp?editors=1111

Comment: let me know if that works, then we will go from there

Comment: i have edit my question with more detail.
i will try your codepen 

Comment: your codepen is too perfect, the json inside bracket. when i try to JSON.Stringify the req.body i get a sentence before json bracket

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ommit the data before and after the outer curly brackets, then i would suggest to run an regex

```
str.replace(/^[^{]*(.*)[^}]*$/,'$1');
```

And the result can be put into the JSON.prase function.

Summary:

```
let trx_id = JSON.parse(result.replace(/^[^{]*(.*)[^}]*$/,'$1')).transaction_id;
```

Comment: (https://i.imgur.com/6gx2NpV.png) Unnecessary escape character